# how to append a read value variable to a file which has double quotes in it

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a variable to a JSON file.

I have tried many sed commands but still cant find a solution

```
#! bin/bash   

echo "Hello"
echo "lets create an instance"

read -p "please enter the type of instance you need: " instance_type

echo $instance_type | sed -i "s|""InstanceType"": """"|""InstanceType"": 
""${instance_type}""|g" awsspotinstancecreation.json
```

```
roxor@ubuntu:~$ bash rough.sh

Hello

lets create an instance

please enter the type of instance you need: t2.small

{
      "ImageId": "ami-074acc26872f26463",

      "KeyName": "Accesskeypair",

      "SecurityGroupIds": ["sg-064caf9c470e4e8e6"],

      **##"InstanceType": "${instance_type}",##**

      "Placement": {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a"
      }
}
```

Comment: Greetings, please provide a [mcve].  Here that means a sample json input, and sample desired json output.  Thirdly what it does right now (so the failing JSON result).  Also look at the help pages for StackOverflow, and learn how to use the editor to format your question.  As is, it is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` has quoting issues as well as the problem of trying to read data from file and STDIN simultaneously.

It's generally a bad idea to use line-oriented tools like `sed`, `grep`, and `awk` to parse or modify JSON. The best shell-based tool for this task is `jq`.

`jq` 1.5+:

```
read -p "Instance type: " instance
export instance
jq '.InstanceType=env.instance' awsspotinstancecreation.json
```

`jq` 1.4+:

```
read -p "Instance type: " instance
jq --arg instance "$instance" '.InstanceType=$instance' awsspotinstancecreation.json
```

Comment: Im getting this error 
parse error: Expected separator between values at line 6, column 14

Comment: @shrikkanthroxor Please update your question to include the actual awsspotinstancecreation.json file

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/). It is meant for exactly this purpose. Here is a [bash](https://github.com/tests-always-included/mo) implementation.

Picked from their site

```
Hello, {{NAME}}.

I hope your {{TIME_PERIOD}} was fun.
```

Command

```
NAME=Tyler TIME_PERIOD=weekend ./mo demo/fun-trip.mo
```

Output

```
Hello, Tyler.

I hope your weekend was fun.
```

It does not matter if the text is in JSON or just plain text as long as the delimiter is clear. Most implementations also give you an option to change the delimiter.

Comment: What advantage does this have over a here-doc?

Comment: Not sure why the comparison. I use mustache quite regularly for de-templatization which is what is being done here.